# (Sharepoint 2007) Send email notification to the current user as well as manager?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have created one custom list.
whenever user add entry to it then email should be triggerd to the manager and the user who has added new entry.
I am using Sharepoint 2007.
Please help.How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to send that email.
I'd recommend to create a EventReceiver or a workflow.

See [How to: Create an Event Handler Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149%28office.12%29.aspx), [Sharepoint Workflow Development (2 part question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300145/sharepoint-workflow-development-2-part-question) and [Good online sources to learn Sharepoint Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915461/good-online-sources-to-learn-sharepoint-development)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the item added event to capture the information about the item being added and use SMTP mail to send the mail to multiple users.Also, you can use the SPUtility.SendEmail function provided by Sharepoint.